# Unable to load asset. Asset is specified in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter

I have a assets folder in my app root, and the image file is assets/amusement/amusement1.jpeg
I have the assets specified in pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

And I'm loading that image:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final wordPair = WordPair.random();
    return Image(image: AssetImage("assets/amusement/amusement1.jpeg"));
  }
```

But I get the error:

```
Error while trying to load an asset: Failed to load asset at "assets/assets/amusement/amusement1.jpeg" (404)
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/amusement/amusement1.jpeg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 236:49  throw_
packages/flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart 227:55                        load
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1362:47                                          _rootRunUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1265:19                                          runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 152:18                                    handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 704:44                                    handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 733:13                                    _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 539:5                                     [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 577:7                                     <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1354:13                                          _rootRun
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1258:19                                          run
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1162:7                                           runGuarded
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1202:23                                          callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15           <fn>

Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/amusement/amusement1.jpeg")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#9d784(), name:
  "assets/amusement/amusement1.jpeg", scale: 1)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I've run `flutter clean` too.

Comment: It’s amusement1.jpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are opening a folder you need to report it to flutter. You have to fix this line with this

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/amusement/
```